# React Native Overflow Touchable is Not Working in Android

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, expo

Please have a look at my [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@jeafgilbert/dropdown).

Dropdown items are touchable in iOS but not in Android. Fixed container's height (grey box) causes this issue but I need to keep the fixed height for my toolbar.

I have tried using `react-native-view-overflow` package but no luck. It requires `react-native link`, meanwhile I can't eject my project because I'm using some Expo packages which will be broken if I eject.

Any suggestion to make the dropdown items touchable in Android?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code, check this : [Snack link](https://snack.expo.io/Bk4fjM2V4)

That's solve your problem but you can update your react-native version to include this [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/b81c8b51fc6fe3c2dece72e3fe500e175613c5d4) that adds support for the `overflow` style property on React Native for Android.

Comment: You make outer container which height is dynamic. I need to have fixed height to create a toolbar. A toolbar should not push any contents below it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when dropdown expands, it flows outside of view because you have given fixed height.

**so for workaround you can use `minHeight` property instead of `height`.**

this will make sure that at least you get your minimum height and if needed it can use more height, like when you are expanding dropdown.

correction is given below,

```
dropdownContainer: {
    width:340,
    minHeight:115,// changed this from height:115
    ...
    ...
  },
```

Comment: I need to have fixed height, a toolbar shouldn’t push any contents below it.